# Finding the new region after changing variables for a double integral.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

I would like to solve the following double integral using the transformation:

$u=x+y$ , $v=x/y$
$$\int _0^1\int _y^2\frac{\left(x+y\right)}{x^2}\:e^{\left(x+y\right)}dxdy$$

What I've reached so far:
$$J=-\frac{u}{\left(v+1\right)^2}$$ , $$x=\frac{uv}{v+1}$$, $$y=\frac{u}{v+1}$$
the only problem I'm facing now is to find the new region so I can set up my double integral, but what I get is:
$$u=0,u=v+1,uv=2\left(v+1\right),v=1 $$
which doesn't look like a region that I can integrate over.

Final note: I know that the integral <s>doesn't converge anyway</s>, and I'm not the one who chose this substitution (homework problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you graph the region bounded by your four curves you can divide it in two regions:
$$
1\leq v\leq 2,\ \ \ 0\leq u\leq v+1
$$
and
$$
2\leq v,\ \ \ 0\leq u\leq \frac{2(v+1)}v.
$$

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that the sign in the straight line $u=v-1$ should be a plus, tried editing but that's just one character.

Comment: Done, thanks.  $ $